# Undefined symbols for architecture i386:"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJsonParser"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5, sbjson

I'm creating a iphone app and its contain SBJson_3.1.1 for login purpose [I'm using webservice for login data] but when I run the project it shows the following error and I cant find what its reason I'm quite new to ios development so please guide me.

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJsonParser", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
>   (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't forgot the header of the class?

Comment: once check SBJsonParser.h  this class was not there in your project.

Comment: Make sure that all the SBJson library are in the "Compile Sources" build phase of your target.

Comment: u mean full class file

Comment: @ThXou I realized my mistake i thought adding one class file is enough anyway thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are building the SBJson library and have linked your app to that, you will need add the `-ObjC` and `-all_load` flags to your linker options.